# Best algorithm to get the minimal intersection of two sets represented as unions.

Tags: combinatorics

I have two sets $A$ and $B$. Set $A$ is itself a union between several sets $A_1, A_2, A_3$.
Hence
$$A = A_1 \cup A_2 \cup A_3$$
and similarly,
$$B = B_1 \cup B_2 \cup B_3.$$

We have the definitions of $A_1,A_2,B_1,B_2$ as comprising of elements, such as:

$$A_1 = \{E_1,E_2,E_3 \cdots\}$$

Now, I want to calculate $A \cap B$ and represent it *minimally*, by that what I mean is it should be represented by an expression of minimal length.

For example, let's say
$$A = A_1 \cup A_2$$
where $A_1 = \{E_1,E_2\}$ and $A_2 = \{E_3,E_4\}$
and $B = A_1 \cup A_3$, where $A_3 = \{E_4,E_6\}$
I want $A \cap B$ to be represented as = $A_1 \cup E_4$ and not $\{E_1, E_2, E_4\}$ as $\{E_1, E_2\}$ are already in $A_1$.
The allowed operation is just union, however in the case when you are not able to represent using a union of sets, feel free to add individual elements by unioning them.

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: What are the operations permitted in the *minimal expression*?

As a concrete example, suppose $A_1 = \{1,2,3\}, A_2 = \{3\}$ and $B_1 = \{2,5\}, B_2 = \{6\}$. We have $A = A_1 \cup A_2 = \{1,2,3\}$ and $B = B_1 \cup B_2 = \{2,5,6\}$ and $A \cap B = \{2\}$. We cannot represent $\{2\}$ using just set-union operations as shown in this example, but we can represent it as $A_1 \cap B_1$. So, you need to clarify what the permitted operations are in the  minimal expression?

Comment: @vvg, I have added the allowed operation, the only one is set union.

Comment: In the general case, it is impossible to represent set intersection with just unions as shown in the example in the previous comment.

Comment: What I meant if you are not able to represent the intersection with unions, consider each element as a single member set and use union. So {2}  can be simply represented as {2} unioned with nothing, if that makes it clear.

Answer (score 1):

Let the basis sets be $A_1, A_2, \cdots, A_m$ and $B_1, B_2, \cdots, B_n$ and $A = \cup_{i=1}^{m} A_i$ and $B = \cup_{j=1}^{n} B_j$. Let $E = \{E_1, E_2, \cdots, E_k\}$ be the universal set of all elements and $A_i \subset E$ and $B_j \subset E$.

In this answer, we denote set difference as $P - Q = \{x | x \in P \land x \notin Q\}$.

1. Compute the intersection $Z \leftarrow A \cap B$.
2. Compute $Y$, the set of subsets of $Z$. We have $|Y| = 2^{|Z|}$.
3. Compute $X \leftarrow \langle X_1, X_2, \cdots X_{|Y|}\rangle$, the sorted sequence of subsets of $Z$ where $|X_i| \gt |X_j|, \forall i \lt j$ (i.e., elements of $Y$, sorted by cardinality).
4. Initialize $M \leftarrow Z, T \leftarrow \emptyset$
5. For $X_i \in X$ and where $M \ne \emptyset$

   If $M \cap X_i = X_i$ then $T \leftarrow T \cup X_i$, $M \leftarrow M - (M \cap X_i)$ End If

   Next
6. Compute $S = \cup_{i} T_i, T_i \in T$. $S$ is a maximal subset that can be generated from the proper subsets of the intersection $Z = A \cap B$. The missing elements, if any, are selected from $E$. i.e., $\Delta = \{ \{ d \} | d \in Z - S \}$.
7. The minimal expression consisting of only set-union operations on the basis sets and elemental sets is then given by $(\cup_{i} T_i) \cup \Delta$.

Note that the running time is exponential in the cardinality of the powerset of the intersection $Y$ i.e., $O(|Y|) = O(2^{|Z|})$ (Step 2) as that dominates the runtime.

**Note:** You don't need the $\Delta$ computation in Step 6. But, one optimization you can do is in step 2. where we put $Y \leftarrow Y - E$ to eliminate the elemental sets and use the $\Delta$ computation only if $Z - S \ne \emptyset$.